# How do I read Registry Key Value

Tags: c++, windows, registry

I am Creating the Registry Key using following code:

```
   LPCTSTR  lpNDS= TEXT("SOFTWARE\\myKEY");
    if(OK==ERROR_SUCCESS)
    {
            MessageBox ( NULL, "Success", 
                             _T("SimpleShlExt"),
                            MB_ICONINFORMATION );
    }
    else
    {
        MessageBox ( NULL, "Failed" ,
                             _T("SimpleShlExt"),
                            MB_ICONINFORMATION );
    }

        LONG openRes = RegCreateKeyEx(
                    HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE,
                    lpNDS,
                    0,
                    NULL,
                    REG_OPTION_NON_VOLATILE,
                    KEY_ALL_ACCESS,
                    NULL,
                    &hRegKey,
                    NULL);

         if (openRes!=ERROR_SUCCESS) 
                MessageBox ( NULL, "Registry Createion Failed", 
                             _T("SimpleShlExt"),
                            MB_ICONINFORMATION );
```

Now I am writing up to the Key using:

```
CSimpleShlExt::WriteToRegistry(LPSTR lpRegKeyVal)
{
        LONG setRes = RegSetValueEx (hRegKey, "NDS", 0, REG_SZ, (LPBYTE)lpRegKeyVal, strlen(lpRegKeyVal)+1);
        CloseRegistryKey();

}
```

Now I am trying read the registry key value that I have created using `WriteToRegistry` function. I have tried with

```
RegOpenKeyEx(hRegKey,lpNDS,0,KEY_QUERY_VALUE,&hRegKey);
```

But this is failing.

Which function shall I use to read the value contained inside the key?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try something like :

```
TCHAR szValue[TEMP_STR_SIZE] = {0};
DWORD dwStorageSize = TEMP_STR_SIZE;
LPBYTE lpStorage = reinterpret_cast<LPBYTE>(szValue);

// In case of registry value retrieval failure
if (ERROR_SUCCESS != RegQueryValueEx(hRegKey, _T("NDS"), 0, 0, lpStorage, &dwStorageSize))
{
    // Prompt error
}
```

Edit: 
Just noticed there are no subkey, changed my sample code

Comment: Now How will I get the Value of the RegistryKey, In My Case , I am writing some value to NDS. *lpStorage is an Integer. Sorry for being so simple but I am just new to this

Comment: if (ERROR_SUCCESS == RegQueryValueEx(hRegKey, _T("NDS"), 0, 0, (BYTE*)szValue, &dwBufSize))
      {
           
           MessageBox ( NULL, szValue, 
                  _T("Value"),
                 MB_ICONINFORMATION );
          
      }

Answer (score 1):

> Which function shall I use to read the value contained inside the key?

Try [`RegQueryValue`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms724909%28VS.85%29.aspx) and/or [`RegEnumValue`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms724865%28VS.85%29.aspx). Read the documentation to see which one suits your needs the best.